# Selecting records based on multiple criteria in a single cell

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working with a database that is set up to show multiple values, separated by commas as shown:

```
txtSiblingsYearList
7,4
9,6
8,3,N
8,3,N
5,3
5,3
```

I need to be able to query this and only bring back records that have at least 2 of R, N, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

I am not sure if this is something that can be done given the way the data is stored within the database table. Does anyone know a way to do this. My current query looks like:

```
    SELECT 
      [txtSchoolID]
      ,[txtTitle]
      ,[txtForename]
      ,[txtSurname]       
      ,[txtForm]
      ,[intNCYear]      
      ,[intFamily]      
      ,[txtSiblingsIDList]
      ,[txtSiblingsNameList]
      ,[txtSiblingsFormList]
      ,[txtSiblingsYearList]      
  FROM [iSAMS].[dbo].[TblPupilManagementPupils]
  Where (intSystemStatus = 1) 
  AND (intNCYear <7) 
  AND (txtSchoolID NOT LIKE txtSiblingsIDList)  
  Order By intFamily
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Shoot the person who decided to use a comma delimited string to represent a set of identifiers in a relational database.

Comment: @MatBailie I totally agree!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be storing lists of values in a comma-delimited string.  That is not the SQL way of doing things.  The resulting queries cannot be optimized, and string functions are not SQL's forte.

If you are stuck with this format, you can add up the number of matches:

```
where ( (case when ',' + txtSiblingsYearList + ',' like '%,R,%' then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when ',' + txtSiblingsYearList + ',' like '%,N,%' then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when ',' + txtSiblingsYearList + ',' like '%,1,%' then 1 else 0 end) +
        . . .
      ) >= 2
```

Comment: Sadly this is a bought application and we have no control over the database or how it is designed. Thank you for your answer I will give it a go and see if it works.

Comment: Gordon - thank you for your answer. I have a slight issue using this code and I am not sure how to fix it. In the instance of twins, where both are in the same year, it is only assigning 1 so then it is not being picked up as >= 2. Is there a way to get around this issue?

Comment: @GemmaDavies . . . Please ask another question with appropriate sample data and desired results.